# How to Pass multiple arrays from a function into main?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Im not used to using pointers or coding in C. I've created a void function in which I defined a couple arrays and populated them using my Input parameters. Now I need to use these arrays in my main but unsure on how to call them. Following is my function code :

```
void showCDF(int Integer_Array[], int length){ //Calculates the CDF and stores it in "y_values"     
    int i = 1;    // i initialized at 1
    int y_axis[20];
    int size_of_x = Integer_Array[length-1]- Integer_Array[0]+1;    // size of x is the difference between the first and 
    int x_axis[size_of_x];            // last element of input array.
    x_axis[0] = Integer_Array[0];     // first element of x is the first element of input array
    //printf("%d ", x_axis[0]);       // print out the first element
    while (x_axis[i-1]<Integer_Array[length-1]){    // while previous element of x < last element of Input
        x_axis[i]= x_axis[i-1] + 1;    // adding the previous value of x to 1 store as this value
        //printf("%d ", x_axis[i]);    // print out all consecutive elements of x
        i +=1;
    }

    printf("\n");
    for (i=0;i<21;i++){
        y_axis[i] = 5*i;
        //printf("%d \n",y_axis[i]);
    }
    int y_values[size_of_x + 1];    // size of y is dependant on the size of x
    for (int j=0; j < size_of_x +1 ; j++){
        float n = 0;    // Count to show total, initialized at 0
        int i= 0;
        while (x_axis[j] >= Integer_Array[i] && i<length){  // While x at j is greater than or equal to values of 
            n ++;    //  Integer_array at i, AND i is less than length.
            i ++;    // Then increase the count and i
        }            //  else:
        y_values[j]=(n/length)*100;     // Then corresponding y at j= % of n / length (or the cdf)
        //printf( "%d ", y_values[j]);  // print out the cdf
    }
}
```

In my main Im calling my function and variables y_axis, y_value, x_axis like this:

```
int y_axis[20]; 
showCDF(integerArray, NUMBER_ENTRIES);
for (i=0;i<21;i++){ 
    printf("%d \n", y_axis[i]);
}
```

But this just gives me a gibberish number like:

0 
0 
0 
0 
0 
0 
0 
0 
0 
0 
0 
0 
1 
0 
4199677 
0 
0 
0 
0 
0 
825307441

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Put all of them in a structure if you know the arrays in advance and return the structure

Comment: If yo have to return multiple arrays from a function, then their is definitely a design issue in your program.

Comment: @RoadRunner-- maybe. There are certainly several [matrix decompositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_decomposition) that one might implement which may involve returning two or three matrices.

Comment: no worries guys! I just added empty Parameters to the function, and used them when I called it in the main. Basically using pointers.

Comment: If all arrays are of the same type, return an array of arrays.